# Как задать максимально возможный DecodePixelWidth для изображения?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

В **WPF** есть **RichTextBox** шириной в 665 device-independents units. Допустим есть изображение с высоким разрешением (11233х6900). То получается для **RichTextBox** все эти 11233 точки не нужны. Мне казалось, что решить проблему можно так (установив просто **DecodePixelWidth** = 665) :

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 665;
bitmap.EndInit();
```

Но если установить **DecodePixelWidth** = 1900, то изображение получается более четким:

```
bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 1900;
```

Как рассчитать максимально подходящее **DecodePixelWidth**?

Comment: Помните, что в WPF мы работаем не с физическими, а с "эффективными" пикселями? Количество физический надо определить отдельно...